# Append a Wildcard * to the end of a variable name for a file

Tags: directory, wildcard, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I am creating txt files on a daily basis in a blob container, I have the date and time appended to the end when it is created.

```
$NewName = (($Blob)+"_"+($CurrentDate))
```

I then want to move it, at the end of the day, to another container, the first part of the filename will always be the same, but obviously the date will change everyday. So I just want to be able to search for the powershell equivalent of $blob*, but I cannot work out how to append a wildcard. 
Second issue I suppose, I'd also ideally use a folder in the same container, but I just cannot work out how to browse to an existing folder in my container to search for a file. I can see the folder when I run...

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $Context -Container $SourceContainer
```

I can see it under the NAME column, but how can I browse to it to then make it a variable pointing to the folder and refer to the file? It seems so straightforward but awkward.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? do you want to move the files in folder_1 to folder_2?

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for getting back. Yes. I can move from container to container, but not from folder to folder within the same container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to close this off in case it helps someone else, I found what I wanted to do here

http://code.commongroove.com/2016/08/03/azure-powershell-copy-blobs-between-storage-accounts/

Thank you to those who took the time to answer and provide help, much appreciated.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
$blob="test20181207"

$s2 = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $context -Container foler1 -Blob "$($blob)*"
```

Note that the $s2 is an array, so you can loop this array for all the matched files.

Test result as below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'll have a go at this and come back.

Comment: Hello, all I am getting when I try to start the blob copy to another container (although the end game will be from a file to another file) is 'StatusMessage:The specified blob does not exist.' I have tried your variable with the wildcard but I all it does in append the filename with a '*', it does not work as a wildcard. I've tried a tonne of combinations, but I cant get a wildcard to work on the variable.

I have a folder called 'file_2018_12_10', saved as $Blob, and want to move it from flda to fldb. Cant browse to folder just container level, cant search for file as $Blob*.

Comment: Hi @DrDuran, could you please give some demo code or pseudo code? So I can help you solve it.